# Unable to import SAP ECC data using SSMS

Tags: ssis, ssms, sql-server-2016, biztalk, sap-erp

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [Import SAP Data Using SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sap/import-sap-data-using-sql-server-management-studio) (Microsoft.com)

However, after I did the Step 5 "Choose a Data Source", the "Import Data" wizard is just disappeared and nothing happens.....

I'm using Windows 2012 R2 and BizTalk adapter pack 2013 R2.

In SSMS, it did show the option for connecting SAP using ".NET Framework Data Provider for mySAP Business Suite

[image: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard screenshot]

After I key in the SAP details and clicked the Next button, the wizard is automatically closed and no error or any warning pop-out. It should pop up "Choose a Destination" dialog box like the Step 6 in the documentation.

What should I do in order to import SAP data into SQL server?

Comment: which  Biztalk Adapter 2013 version do you have? have you tried to install [cumulative update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/cumulative-update-package-2-for-biztalk-adapter-pack-2013-819ea90d-0252-8650-8323-b49b0a36ee5d) for it? what SAP ECC version do you have?

Comment: @Suncatcher I'm using BizTalk Adapter Pack 2013 R2 and I think the version is 1 (I downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38170)

SAP Version is SAP ECC 6.0

Comment: The cumulative update is only for Biztalk adapter 2013, not Biztalk adapter 2013 R2, right?

Comment: For BizTalk 2013 R2, the CUs contain all the updates "BizTalk Server, Adapter Pack, and Accelerators are all part of single download."   Are you on CU8 for BizTalk 2013 R2?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf For my case, I only download the adapters without server. I've tried to download and run CU8, however it shows "BiztalkServer2013R2 not found or this package does not contain compatible update." [KB 4052527]

Comment: Are you sure you have BizTalk Server 2013 R2 on not BizTalk Server 2013 then? That article you link to looks to be SSIS, rather than BizTalk.   Do you have BizTalk Server installed at all?  You can't use the Adapter Pack without it so far as I know

Comment: ok, will check on that, but do I need to do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sap/install-custom-rfcs-for-the-data-provider-for-sap), will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I found out that I didn't install Data Provider for SAP and RFCs.

1. Install BizTalk adapters
2. SAP Logon (or other Data Provider for SAP) must be installed.
3. Must install RFCs to SAP before you query in the Import Data task. See [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sap/install-custom-rfcs-for-the-data-provider-for-sap)
4. Follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sap/import-sap-data-using-sql-server-management-studio) to import your data